# Callback on last promise from an array of Mongo updates

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, promise

I would like to have a function called on the return of the last promise made during a forEach() loop.

Sample code:

```
var mainList = getArrayData()

mainList.forEach((item,i)=>{
    mongooseSchema.find(_id:item.id).exec((err,doc)=>{
        doStuff(doc)
    })
})
```

Any code after the second block will run immediately after all the mongo queries are sent off. If you wrap the whole thing in a promise (i.e. the array data is from a separate mongo query) you still get the same effect.

Is there any way I can have a special function/callback for the last query, or even better, a promise that returns after all the queries have returned?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Promise.all. It will fire off once all of the promises in an array are resolved.

> The Promise.all(iterable) method returns a promise that resolves when all of the promises in the iterable argument have resolved, or rejects with the reason of the first passed promise that rejects.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

```
var mainList = getArrayData()
let promises = [];

mainList.forEach((item,i)=>{
    let p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        mongooseSchema.find(_id:item.id).exec((err,doc)=>{
            doStuff(doc)
            resolve();
        });
    });
    promises.push(p);
});

Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
    // do something when all are resolved
});
```

Comment: however beware:
"Promise.all is rejected if one of the elements is rejected".

Comment: I wouldn't say that's something to "beware" of, rather something that should be planned for with an efficient error handling method.

Comment: This looks like exactly what I need, thanks! Once I get this working I'll mark answered.